# Variable in Info.plist being interpreted literally

Tags: xcode, info.plist

In my info.plist I have `CFBundleShortVersionString` set to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` and this has always worked fine until a recent update where now if I grab the version via PlistBuddy, it's literally the string "$(MARKETING_VERSION)" not the actual version (ex. 1.7.4).

Not sure if this is a Catalina thing or Xcode 11 thing. Are there any workarounds besides manually setting the version?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.